# MySQL trigger can't update own table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have the following MySQL tables:

```
create table JCMA_USER(
    id_registred_user    bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email                varchar(150) not null,
    password             varchar(150) not null,
    name                 varchar(250),
    ...);

create table JCMA_ORDER(
    id_order             bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_registred_user    bigint not null,
    reference_number     varchar(250) not null,
    ...)

create table JCMA_ORDER_LINE(
    id_order_line        bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_order             bigint not null,
    quantity             int not null,
    ...);

create table JCMA_PRODUCT(
    id_product           bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_order_line        bigint not null,
    job_title            varchar(250),
    keywords             text,
    ...);
```

Linked with one to many associations:
A `JCMA_USER` have n `JCMA_ORDER`, a `JCMA_ORDER` have n `JCMA_ORDER_LINE` and a `JCMA_ORDER_LINE` have n `JCMA_PRODUCT`.

I want to keep the `keywords` column from table `JCMA_PRODUCT` having as value the concatenation string of `name` from table `JMCA_USER` and `job_title` from table `JMCA_PRODUCT`.

So i created the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER clad_keywords_insert AFTER INSERT
ON JCMA_PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE JCMA_PRODUCT SET keywords = (SELECT concat(coalesce(new.job_title, ''), ' ', coalesce(U.name, ''))
                                        FROM JCMA_PRODUCT P
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN JCMA_ORDER_LINE OL ON OL.id_order_line = P.id_order_line
                                                INNER JOIN JCMA_ORDER O ON O.id_order = OL.id_order
                                                INNER JOIN JCMA_USER U ON U.id_registred_user = O.id_registred_user
                                        WHERE P.id_product = new.id_product)
    WHERE id_product = new.id_product;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But i get the following MySQL error:

```
Can't update table 'jcma_product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I think that means that i can't update a row in the same table as the trigger. From what i found on internet it's not allowed in MySQL.

Is there a workaround to achieve this? Have i to create a KEYWORD table especially for this MySQL limitation?